# Properties of Jacobian

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Consider the transformation from $\mathbf z_0$ to $\mathbf z$, where $\mathbf z_0$ and $\mathbf z$ are function of N variables. Let $J_{rs}$ be the cofactor of $\partial z_r / \partial z_s^0$ in the Jacobian determinant.

Then $$J_{rs} = J\partial z_s^0/ \partial z_r $$

I know from Laplace's theorem we have $$J=\sum_{r=1}^N  J_{rs}\partial z_r / \partial z_s^0$$ How do we get the required expression? It seems I just need to move the partial derivative to other side, but it is a sum.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\partial z^0_s}{\partial z_r}$ is the $(r,s)$-component of the inverse Jacobian matrix

$J$ is the Jacobian (determinant)

It follows that:

$J\frac{\partial z^0_s}{\partial z_r}$ is the $(r,s)$-component of the adjugate of the Jacobian matrix, because given an invertible matrix $A$: $\operatorname{Adj}A=\det A\cdot A^{-1}$

So it is not the $(r,s)$-cofactor of the Jacobian matrix.